# ReactJS global state toggle

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactJS and stuck in an issue. i have a button in header that needs to toggle a class 'show' in a menu which is in some other file. I tried to use global state but do not know how to do that. here is what i did;

**LAYOUT FILE**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// importing header / menu etc.

function LayoutHome({ children }) {
const [state, setState] = React.useState({ MsgMenu: 'messages-dropdown' });
const handleOpenMsgMenu =  (e) => {        
    e?.preventDefault();
    setState({MsgMenu:'messages-dropdown show'});
};
return (
    <>
        <Header handleOpenMsgMenu={handleOpenMsgMenu} />
        <MessageMenu  handleOpenMsgMenu={state.MsgMenu} />
        {children}
        <Footer />


    </>
);
}
```

**HEADER**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function Header({handleOpenMsgMenu}) {
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOpenMsgMenu} className="header-notification-btn">MENU</button >
}
```

**MENU**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function MessageMenu({handleOpenMsgMenu}) {
    <div id="messages-dropdown" className={handleOpenMsgMenu}>
    // CONTENT
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Look into react useContext.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use useState hook to toggle the display of the Menu.
create a new toggle state in global and pass it onto the menu component.
below is the complete code.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App({children}) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ MsgMenu: 'messages-dropdown' });
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);

const handleOpenMsgMenu =  (e) => {        
    e?.preventDefault();
    setToggle(!toggle);
};

return (
    <>
        <Header handleOpenMsgMenu={handleOpenMsgMenu} />
        <MessageMenu  handleOpenMsgMenu={state.MsgMenu} toggle={toggle} />
        {children}
    </>
);
}
```

// Header

```
import React from "react";
    function Header({handleOpenMsgMenu}) {
      return <button type="button" onClick={handleOpenMsgMenu} className="header-notification-btn">MENU</button >
    }
```

// Menu

```
import React from "react";
    function MessageMenu({handleOpenMsgMenu, toggle}) {
      return <div id="messages-dropdown" style={{display: toggle?"block":"none"}}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          {handleOpenMsgMenu}
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle state with `!value` and then change your class depending on that value

```js
    setMenu(() => {
      return {
        ...menu,
        show: !menu.show // toggle
      };
    });
```

I've made a sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lucy-1ek2uz)

For the global state, check out [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)

Comment: is there a way to trigger this toggle also when clicked anywhere else outside the menu?